# Bends in piping

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, volume

Plumbers made an error. Where there was one 90 degree elbow, there is now two 90 degree elbows within 1 ft of plumbing. I'm concerned about a loss of pressure or volume due to the extra elbow?

Comment: Resistance (pressure drop / volume flow rate) for 2 bends would be twice that for 1 bend (to a first approximation).